# Various problems in JSHint

Tags: javascript

In JSHint I get the follwing message about my array declaration:

```
jesuschrist["eng_male"] = [//tons of arrays here];
```

> ['baby_jesus'] is better written in dot notation.

Does it mean I should write it as `baby.jesus`?

---

Also, I gives me a problem when declaring the object:

```
jesuschrist = new Object();
```

JSHint says this:

> Use the object literal notation {}.

Comment: Please choose more appropriate "meaningless" variable names in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's suggesting that your code change to:

```
jesuschrist = {};
jesuschrist.eng_male = [//tons of arrays here];
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is dot notation better anyways?

Comment: 3 characters less, looks better.

Comment: It's cleaner and it emphasizes that you're dealing with an object and not an associative array (even though it acts just like one!).

Comment: Use [] when the key is a computed value, since you're then using the object as an array. When it's a literal, you're using it as an object and should use dot notation to make this intent clear.

Comment: @Barmar You're first sentence doesn't make sense. He's using an object as an object, just using a different notation. The brackets are just another way of accessing properties.

Comment: @Barmar That sounds like it could work. I use it to detect the values between the underscore. Like this: if the user has chosen eng_male, the language will be english and the gender of the name will be male. Pretty simple and genious. My uncle did this to me and he is a Java developer, maybe this is the reason it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

jShint tell you to use do notation because you are trying to get property with a string literal(which is static). Because property identifier wont change.

```
jesuschrist.eng_male //this wont change
```

You can access property of an object using [] but then pass property name as variable(which can be dynamic)

```
var prop = "eng_male";
jesuschrist[prop]; //this might be changed, depends on the prop value.
```

Both given examples are ok with JsHint.

Comment: So, I can't change the value? It's an variable now. A variable for the human, not for the computer (variable name can be seen by humans, but not the computer. Humans can also see the value like the computer)

Comment: You can change it, its only of matter how compiler interprets your code. At the time compiler gets to the jesuschrist.eng_male the eng_male is already a name of the property you want to get(its therefore 'static'). If compiler gets to the jesuschrist[prop]; prop might be anything you want(therefore dynamic). Using dynamic access to property with [] when in fact the property name is static literal is a redundant action. Thats why JsHint says "Its better to write in a dot notation..".

Comment: that makes much more sense. While the the Closure Compiler gives my code as a 0 byte!